# Devolver last_id al añadir en AJAX

Tags: ajax

Tengo este código que me crea un libro con AJAX y necesito que me devuelva la ultima id insetada para redireccionar a la página. He probado a hacerlo pero me devuelve 'undefined'.

AJAX ADD

```
$('#btn-addbook').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.validate({
        rules: {
            isbn: {
                required: true
            },
            titulo: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
    if (!form.valid()) {
        return;
    }
    btn.addClass('kt-spinner kt-spinner--right kt-spinner--sm kt-spinner--light').attr('disabled', true);
    form.ajaxSubmit({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './index.php?action=book-add',
        cache: 'false',
        beforeSend: function(){
            toastr.success("Please, wait a moment...", "Creating new Book");
        },
        success: function(response, status, xhr, $form) {
          toastr.clear();
          toastr.success("New Book created!", "Completed!");
          var msg = response.msg;
          var last_id = response.last_id;
          setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.replace("./copies/".last_id);
          }, 2000);
        },
        error: function() {
          toastr.error("Please try again...", "Error!");
        }
    });
});
```

book-add.php

```
<?php
// print_r($_SESSION);
if(count($_POST)>0){
  $a = new SQLMan();
  $a->tablename = "libro";
  $numpag = $_POST["num_pag"];
  $year = $_POST["year"];
  $description = $_POST["description"];
  $type = "1";
    
  if (isset($_POST["categoria_id"])) { $categories = $_POST["categoria_id"]; } else {}
  if (isset($_POST["nivel_id"])) { $niveles = $_POST["nivel_id"]; } else {}
    
  if ($_POST["autor_id"]>0) { $a->autor_id = $_POST["autor_id"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["editorial_id"]>0) { $a->editorial_id = $_POST["editorial_id"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["num_pag"]>0) { $a->num_pag = $_POST["num_pag"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["year"]>0) { $a->anio = $_POST["year"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["description"]>0) { $a->description = $_POST["description"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["default_price"]>0) { $a->default_price = $_POST["default_price"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["amortization_id"]>0) { $a->amortization_id = $_POST["amortization_id"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["language_id"]>0) { $a->language_id = $_POST["language_id"]; } else {}
  if ($_POST["asignatura_id"]>0) { $a->asignatura_id = $_POST["asignatura_id"]; } else {}
    
  $b = new SQLMan();
  $b->tablename = "categoriavslibro";
    
  $d = new SQLMan();
  $d->tablename = "nivelvslibro";

  // $a->in_test = true;
  $a->isbn = $a->is_string($_POST["isbn"]);
  $a->titulo = $a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["titulo"])));
  $a->subtitulo = $a->is_string(ucwords(mb_strtolower($_POST["subtitulo"])));
  $a->type = $a->is_string($type);
  $a->creator_id = $a->is_string($_POST["creator_id"]);
  list($rs,$lastid)=$a->add();

    if (isset($_POST["categoria_id"])) { 
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $b->libro_id = $a->is_string($lastid);
            $b->categoria_id = $a->is_string($cat);
            $b->add();
        }
    } else {}
    
    if (isset($_POST["nivel_id"])) { 
        foreach ($niveles as $nivel) {
            $d->libro_id = $a->is_string($lastid);
            $d->nivel_id = $a->is_string($nivel);
            $d->add();
        }
    } else {}
    
    $data['msg'] = "success";
    $data['last_id'] = $lastid;

    echo json_encode($data);

  Core::redir("./copies/".$lastid);
}

?>
```

Comment: Dentro de `success` pon un `console.log(response);` y dinos qué datos ves en la consola de Javascript. Yo veo que tu petición Ajax se dirige a `index.php` pero el archivo que está supuesto a procesar los datos es otro. No sé si en tu caso `index.php` hace de controlador y dirige el tráfico a `book-add.php`¿?

Comment: Esto me muestra en la consola: {"msg":"success","last_id":412} No sé porque no me hace el window.location.replace bien si devuelve la id bien...

Comment: Por lo que veo me falla la parte de var last_id = response.last_id; que no guarda el id en la variable...

Comment: Siempre es más seguro trabajar con JSON (menos propenso a errores) y también más ligero. No te funciona porque debes poner en Ajax un parámetro `dataType: 'json'` para que Ajax haga el parse de la respuesta, entonces podrás leerlo así: `response.last_id`

Comment: Lo he probado y perfecto, ponlo como respuesta si quieres para que pueda marcarla. Gracias! @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás recibiendo los datos así:

```
{"msg":"success","last_id":412}
```

y no te está funcionando la lectura de JSON es porque debes poner en Ajax un parámetro [`dataType`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), para que Ajax haga el parse de la respuesta convirtiéndola a un objeto JSON.

El parámetro se indica así:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Entonces podrás leer la respuesta así:

```
response.last_id
```

Generalmente en las peticiones Ajax es mejor trabajar con respuestas JSON, es un formato ligero, menos propenso a errores y te permite además trabajar con datos estructurados.

Answer (score 0):

cuando recibis los datos. En tu configuracion ajax estas recibiendo texto plano no un objeto json.
Tenes que parsear para acceder a los objetos ejemplo: dentro de la funcion success de ajax.

```
    //Convertimos el string a un objeto JSON.
    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
    //Accedemos a las propiedades.
    var msg = data.msg;
    var last_id = data.last_id;
```